# check id isKindOfType CFType

Tags: objective-c, core-data, plist

Shortly: how to determine **if id is CFType or not at runtime**

i'm implementing [dynamic core data attributes](http://www.2pi.dk/tech/cocoa/dynamic_attributes.html) and in willSave method of ExtendedManagedObject i wanna check if the id value is CFType to store it into plist file.

If I'm trying to save to plist UIImage, that is not toll-free bridged with CF ([apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html)), I am getting an error:

2011-11-17 17:16:25.294 [490:707] Error saving extended data: Property list invalid for format (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')

Can I check it with some method or I have to implement by myself (just isKindOfClass from docs)?

I don't want to implement accessors in NSManagedObject subclass, I dont know exactly how many urls I'll get from entities properties. Question is about dynamic extended attributes at runtime.

```
- (void)willSave
{
NSDictionary *changes = [self valueForKey:@"extendedChanges"];
if (changes!=nil) {
    // merge changes into snapshot
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[self extendedSnapshot] mutableCopy];
    NSEnumerator *e = [changes keyEnumerator];
    NSString *key;
    while (key=[e nextObject]) {
        id value = [changes objectForKey:key];



        if (value==[NSNull null])
            [dict removeObjectForKey:key];
        else if (#ugly and I'm not shure is thread safe **else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSData class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])**)
            [dict setObject:value forKey:key];
    }

    // archive as binary plist
    NSData *data = nil;
    if ([dict count]>0) {
        NSString *error=nil;
        data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dict 
                                                          format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving extended data: %@", error);
            [error release];
        }
    }
    [dict release];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:data forKey:@"extendedData"];
}
[super willSave];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a wrong way to approach the problem. The blog post you referenced saves the extended attributes as a serialized plist. The plist can contain only the following types of objects, as written in the [official doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html):

> `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSDate`, `NSData`, `NSString` and `NSNumber`.

Other classes are just not allowed. Don't add objects of any other class to the attributes extended this way.

Also, saving an image file in a CoreData database is not a good idea, generally speaking, read [On Blobs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW5) in the official doc. Instead, save the `UIImage` in a file and write the file path in the CoreData database.

---

If you just have a transient property which is not saved to the database, you don't even have to go through the trouble of creating extended attributes. Just add it as a property of a subclass of `NSManagedObject`:

```
@interface MyManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
}
@property(retain, nonatomic) UIImage* thumbnail;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSDictionary* thumbnailDictionary;
@end
```

without adding `thumbnail` in the CoreData model. Then do the corresponding `@synthesize`  in the `.m` file. The property added this way to a managed object is just not saved.

If you want to keep unknown number of thumbnails, you can put an `NSDictionary` (or `NSArray`) containing `UIImage*`s.

---

If you really do want to get `CFType` from an `NSObject*`, do the following:

```
NSObject* x= ...;
CFTypeID typeID=CFGetTypeID((CFTypeRef)x);
if(typeID != CFStringGetTypeID() &&
   typeID != CFDateGetTypeID() &&
   typeID != CFDataGetTypeID() &&
   typeID != CFDictionaryGetTypeID() &&
   typeID != CFArrayGetTypeID()  ) {
       ... it's a non-plistable type ...
}
```

The ugly `if` clause is there because there's no public function which gives you the `CFTypeID` of an un-bridged Objective-C object. 
Read [CFType](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001203) reference. But I don't recommend doing this.

Comment: thank you, but I want to store pointer to UIImage at runtime without adding properties to NSManagedObject subclass, but just by 

UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageWithData:loadeddata] retain];
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [prsn setValue:pathToCachedFile forExtendedKey:@"thumbnailPath"];
                     [cell.imageView setImage:img];
                     [prsn setValue:img forExtendedKey:@"thumbnailPointer"];
                 }); 

And i want to skip this types while saving to persistant store in -(void)willSave method.

Comment: >but I want to store pointer to UIImage at runtime without adding properties to NSManagedObject subclass; 

also I want to store Path to core data
[prsn setValue:pathToCachedFile forExtendedKey:@"thumbnailPath"];

I need a pointer to UIImage only at runtime

Comment: The answer I wrote should cover your situation. But I advise you to update the model to include the cache path, if your iOS app hasn't shipped.

Comment: why i should update data model? Extended attributes work perfectly. My question is about determining if id is CFType or not at runtime. however thanks 4 advice

Answer (score 0):

Trying to store an image in `UIImage` format also results in "property lists cannot contain objects of type `CFType` error. Best way is to convert `UIImage` to `NSData` before writing to pList.