# Having trouble deleting Identity from keychain

Tags: ios, keychain

I have an app with some identities stored inside its keychain.

When I try to delete one of them using a search query I get an errSecParam error.

If I try to delete using a kSecMatchLimitList attribute (as explained in the Apple reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemDelete) where I specify the SecIdentityRef value I get this error message at the output:

```
Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'SecIdentity')
```

Whereas I've found some SO related posts about this issue...

- [ios/SecItemDelete not accepting a SecIdentityRef/kSecMatchItemList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516295/ios-secitemdelete-not-accepting-a-secidentityref-ksecmatchitemlist)
- [check id isKindOfType CFType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168012/check-id-iskindoftype-cftype)

...none of them seem to solve my problem.

Did anyone run through this?